# Можно ли вывести юзеров определённого пола ВКонтакте API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
$resp2 = $VK->api('users.get', array('uids' => $array_uid, 'fields' => 'photo_big, sex'));
```

Можно как-нибудь выводить например пользователей **только женского** пола?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Описание полей параметра fields](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0_fields)

> Поле sex
>
> Возвращаемые значения: 1 - женский, 2 - мужской, 0 - без указания пола.

Пройдитесь по вашему `$resp2` и проверяйте, что `sex=='1'`.